# GDAL Import Error after freezing Python 3 script

Tags: python, py2exe, cx-freeze, gdal

I am trying to freeze a Python script that contains an import from `osgeo` but the executable fails with an `ImportError: No module named '_gdal'`.

I've stripped down my script to just one line:

`import osgeo`

When running in Python (version 3.3.3) all is well. I've tried freezing with cx_Freeze and py2exe. Both report that there is a missing module: `? _gdal imported from osgeo` (among others) but successfully freeze the script. Then the exe fails with the above ImportError.

I've tried importing `_gdal` in python and it works. I tried manually including the `osgeo` module in the freezing options but still get the same error.

There is a similar question here:
[Importing GDAL with cx_Freeze, Python3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998862/importing-gdal-with-cx-freeze-python3-4)
but maybe this isn't a cx_freeze issue because it also happens with py2exe (it has experimental support for python 3 now).

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Same question I asked the last person with this problem: if you do `import _gdal` and then `print(_gdal)` in a Python prompt, what does it show you?

Comment: @ThomasK importing `_gdal` fails unless I import `osgeo` first. After I do that, `print(_gdal)` prints: `<module '_gdal' from 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\osgeo\\_gdal.pyd'>`

Comment: Oh, swig is doing funny things. Try going into `C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py` and editing line 13 (ish) from `import _gdal` to `from . import _gdal`, and then freezing again. Here's the file as I'm suggesting you change it: https://gist.github.com/takluyver/ac036f733c6f79342780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix. I edited the `osgeo\__init__.py` file and modified line 13 like this: import `osgeo._gdal`. This works but only if the module osgeo._gdal is manually included when freezing. @Thomas K Your solution does the same thing I guess.

Note that the same modification must be applied both at `osgeo.ogr` (line 18) and `osgeo.osr` (line 18) modules if they are needed (`import osgeo._ogr` and `import osgeo._osr` respectively). This means that these must be manually included when freezing as well. My freezing command now looks like this: `python cxfreeze.py module1.py --include-modules=osgeo._gdal,osgeo._ogr,osgeo._osr`.

Thanks @Thomas K for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I have an issue open on SWIG about this: https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/145